# Android Question Marks in ReadLine

Tags: java, android, string, encoding, utf-8

hi i am building a messaging app that uses tcp and whenever i send a string with Hebrew chars im getting question marks and i have already tried converting the string using new String(serverMessage.getBytes(),"UTF-8");
but it didn't work here is my code:

```
   try {
            //send the message to the server
            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
            //receive the message that the server sends back
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            HelloService.firstTouch();


            //in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the server
            while (mRun) {
                serverMessage = in.readLine();
                String temmmd = new String(serverMessage.getBytes("UTF-8"),"UTF-8");

                if (serverMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                    //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class to inform main activity that a message has received
                    mMessageListener.messageReceived(temmmd);
                }
                serverMessage = null;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

        } finally {

            socket.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

Comment: Your null check is in the wrong place. It needs to be the first thing after `readLine()`.

Comment: i know i did that just to test it and it dosnt matter thats not my question